# Swift 4.2.1 requesting JSON with Xcode 10.1

Tags: swift4.2

My code:

```
let cgpurl = URL(string: "https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/ping")!
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: cgpurl) { (Data, URLResponse, Error) in
if let data = Data, let string = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) { 
let CGPing = string } ; resume() }
```

The problem is with the 2nd use of "cgpurl". I've tried changing case to no effect. The error I'm getting is, "Cannot use instance member 'cgpurl' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available". Ok... but I can't even replace cgpurl with the actual link? Then I get the error message "Ambiguous reference to member 'dataTask(with:completionHandler:)'" I realize this release of swift was supposed to be "small" & just to "fix errors" but I've not been able to find any current documentation on this release. I'm using swift 4.2.1 with Xcode 10.1

Comment: The parameters in the completion closure are parameter labels, not types `} (data, response, error) in`

Comment: Even if I change it to (data, response, error) I'm getting the same error message. This code was taken directly from a teaching manual for Swift 4.2 I know it's wrong but that isn't the question. I'm asking how to fix it as I can't seem to find a reliable source of information on 4.2.1 which supposedly only fixed errors in 4.2 (when this code was working).

Answer (score 0):

> This code was taken directly from a teaching manual for Swift 4.2

No, it wasn't. The code *you* have was never right, in Swift 4.2 or any other version of Swift. You have blindly copied and pasted perhaps, without looking at the overall context.

The problem is that the code, as you have it, is sitting "loose" at the top of your view controller or other class declaration, perhaps something along these lines:

```
class MyViewController : UIViewController {
    let cgpurl = // ...
    let task = // ...
}
```

That's wrong. The most basic rule of Swift programming is that executable code can exist only in a *function*. For example:

```
class MyViewController : UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let cgpurl = // ...
        let task = // ...
    }
}
```

That may not solve all your issues, but at least you'll get past the most basic mistake you're making and the "Cannot use instance member" compile error will go away.

Comment: This sits inside of it's own class I just thought listing the class here was a waste of space & was a "no duh" thing.

Comment: In a class but not any _function_ (method) in that class. Read my answer!

Comment: I did read your answer Matt & discounted it because it doesn't resolve the problem at hand.